# Select which column I receive the results from in data.table join - R

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to select the column I want to receive the results from by passing it in the join.

My data take the following format:

```
tab1 = data.table(z = c(1,2,3,4),
                  x = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  y = c("E", "F", "G", "H"))

tab2 = data.table(z = c(1,2,3,4),
                  column = c("x", "x", "y", "y"))
```

I have tried the following solutions and they do not work:

```
# solutions that dont work
tab2[, val := tab1[tab2, on = .(z), get(i.column)]]
tab2[, val := tab1[tab2, on = .(z), column, with=F]]
```

I am trying to join `tab2` to `tab1` and return the results from either column `x` or `y` depending on which is evaluated from the `column` field.

The results should look like:

```
| z | column | val |
--------------------
| 1 | x      | A   |
| 2 | x      | B   |
| 3 | y      | G   |
| 4 | y      | H   |
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the `by` argument

```
tab2[tab1, val := get(column), on = .(z), by = .EACHI]
```

-output

```
> tab2
   z column val
1: 1      x   A
2: 2      x   B
3: 3      y   G
4: 4      y   H
```

Comment: is there a way to add a condition to this query? specifically, where tab2's `column` is not `NA`?

Comment: @Laurence_jj can you show an example and expected

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "SQL-style" answer which requires to reshape `tab2` from wide to long format. Then, the columns names become data items.

```
tab2[, val := melt(tab1, id.var = "z")[tab2, on = .(z, variable = column), value]]
tab2
```

> ```
>    z column val
> 1: 1      x   A
> 2: 2      x   B
> 3: 3      y   G
> 4: 4      y   H
> ```